# Adding a new column to the table depends on a date column of the table(unpivot)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table have 2 columns creation date and deletion date, And I want to have a new table looks like screenshot, anyone knows how to do it

raw data

| Creation date | Deletion date |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-06 | 2023-01-07 |
| 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-08 |

What i want is

| Date | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-06 | Creation |
| 2023-01-07 | Creation |
| 2023-01-08 | Creation |
| 2023-01-08 | Deletion |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION` two queries such this.

```
select creation_date as event_date, 'Creation' as status
from table_name
union all
select deletion_date, 'Deletion'
from table_name
--order by event_date, status
```

| event_date | status |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-06 | Creation |
| 2023-01-07 | Deletion |
| 2023-01-08 | Creation |
| 2023-01-08 | Deletion |

---

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Isolated

another solution i found is

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM (SELECT created, deleted FROM public.table_name) UNPIVOT (
>     date FOR type IN (created, deleted)
> );
> ```